# Spring 3.2.13 + Hibernate 4.2.7 + JTA: works on tomee with jotm but fails on WebLogic 12c

Tags: spring, hibernate, weblogic12c, jta, tomee-7

I am upgrading the stack of old app. I was able to test the JTA piece on tomcat/tomee(1.7.4) successfully, but when I try to deploy the same WAR file to WebLogic [12c], it fails to connect to data base with following stack trace. Both my hibernate config files look like below:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<mapping resource=“com/example/xyz.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is how my context piece:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package=“com.example”/>
<bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
<property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true"/></bean>

<bean id="transactionDefinition" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition">
<property name="isolationLevelName" value="ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED"/>
<property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
<property name="timeout" value="30"/>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id=“ds1" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/DS1"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ds2" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/DS2"/>

<bean id=“ds1SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref=“ds1"/>
<property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.default_schema”>TEST1</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml”/>
</bean>
```

The session factory for second data source is similar to this one. And this is the stack trace I get:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2371)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2334)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1275)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
...
at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp.__dc._jsp__tag0(__dc.java:125)
    at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp.__dc._jspService(__dc.java:96)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    ...
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    ...
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: User: TEST_USER, failed to be authenticated.
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.wrapAndThrowResourceException(JDBCUtil.java:278)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:416)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: User: TEST_USER, failed to be authenticated.
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getSubject(RmiDataSource.java:473)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:407)
    ... 81 more>
```

I already tried with multiple spring/hibernate version combination as well as different hibernate properties in my session factory bean! I already tested the datasource definitions on WebLogic and they are able to connect to database.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the issue in my settings. Hibernate was trying to connect to database as if it was a normal JDBC connection. After removing  this line: `<property name="dataSource" ref=“ds1"/>` from sessionFactory definition it started working.